# Code not generating expected output

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to rectify the particular problem which I got in my interview(**The problem was to find the smallest element with the frequency exactly f**). I think I have devised the solution to the great extent but the problem is regarding some glitch which is in turn generating some wrong output.I have tried everything, checked and rechecked the code but the problem still persists. Since I am a **beginner** in java programming and therefore do not have much idea about it so please help me. Below is what I tried:

```
public static int smallestKFreq(int a[], int n, int f)
    {
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

        // Map is used to store the count of
        // elements present in the array
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++)

            if (map.containsKey(a[i]))
                map.put(a[i], m.get(a[i]) + 1);

            else map.put(a[i], 1);

        // Traverse the map and find minimum
        // element with frequency f.
        int res = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        Set<Integer> s = map.keySet();

        for (int temp : s)
            if (map.get(temp) == f)
                res = Math.min(res, temp);

        return (res != Integer.MAX_VALUE)? res : 1;
    }
```

Comment: *"Code is generating compile-time error"* ***What*** compile-time error?!

Comment: Sir it is generating different output!!!`{1,2,3,2,2,1,3}` then output is `3`

Comment: So... **not** a compile-time error.

Comment: Yes Sir but expected output is different than original!!!I meant to say that

Answer (score 0):

Okay So looking at your question it seems like you have wrong `return` statement!!!

It should be

`return (res !=Integer.MAX_VALUE)?res : -1;`

Try this I think it should fix the problem...

Comment: Thank you @mandy8055, it worked but please will you tell me why replacing `-1` works?

Comment: @BaijNR If you have understood the logic which you wrote then it clearly says that return the result with minimum value and with maximum frequency so the result must either return that element or nothing at all...